# ID inserted using ASP Web APi appearing as empty in MySql? c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, rest

I have create a Rest web api using ASP.net. When I insert new data using the api, the ID appearing as empty in Mysql workbench. Other columns apart of ID can get the data I'm inserting. When I try to insert new data, it gives me exception Duplicate entry '' for Primary key.

Insert code in DBconn.cs

```
public void addMeterReading(string id, string machinemeterreadingid, int reading)
    {
        MySqlConnection myconn = getDBConn();
        String sqlstr = "INSERT INTO actualmeterreading (ID ,MachineMeterReadingId,ActualReading) VALUES ('" + id + "','" + machinemeterreadingid + "', "+reading+")";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlstr, myconn);
        myconn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myconn.Close();
        myconn.Dispose();

    }
```

POST api code

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route ("api/ActualMeterReading/{id}/{machinemeterid}/{reading}")]
    public void Post([FromBody]string id, string machinemeterid, int reading)
    {
        DBConn db = new DBConn();
        db.addMeterReading(id, machinemeterid, reading);
    }
```

[Data entering and output in MySql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T99Cj.jpg)

[Table defination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtm6u.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain what exactly your problem is?

Comment: How have you defined the `ID` column in your table? If you don't tell anyone to fill it, it stays empty of course. Do you actually want to insert a client-provided ID or should the ID be generated by the database? (Real ID's coming from a client are usually a _very_ bad idea!)

Comment: The ID column is defined in the column and the ID will be Guid which will be created later. It will be autogenerated by my app.

Comment: please the link to see the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/T99Cj.jpg

Comment: @batwing, can you please provide the definition for your database table? Is your `ID` column marked as identity? If so, do you have `identity insert` option enabled in your database?

Comment: my table is like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtm6u.jpg

Comment: You can not generate the ID after insertion because at some point you will have double ID's, which your table definition prohibits. Why don't you just check `Generated` for that column, and give it an actually useful datatype (varchar for a PK? Really!?) Let the database do what it's good at. Let it handle ID's!

Comment: @oerkelens I need to use guid. Thats the requirement, need to varchar

Comment: Generate the guid before you do the insert, then. You do not need the Id as a parameter into your functions anywhere - but you might want to consider using it as a return parameter if the client should want to update the record later.

Comment: [This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57293/mysql-alter-table-to-automatically-put-in-a-uuid) might help if you want to use a trigger to generate your ID.